Integrar campo Serie para registrar Boletas - Oracle 11g
Estoy utilizando Oracle 11g, tengo una tabla llamada BOLETA, con el campo NUMERO como PK, el requisito es registrar el número de serie de la boleta, por tal razón se agrego el campo SERIE.
imagen de tabla BOLETA
mi duda es, ¿Cómo puedo permitir el registro de números de boletas iguales pero con diferente serie, asimismo, no permitir el registro de un número de boleta igual con la misma serie?
Por ejemplo, insertando los siguientes datos:



NUMERO
SERIE
Estado




10
A
Permitido


10
B
Permitido


10
A
No permitido, número y serie ya registrado


20
A
Permitido



El inconveniente esta con el campo NUMERO, ya que es la PK, entonces al insertar un mismo número pero con diferente serie, muestra que el registro ya existe.
Por ejemplo, insertando los siguientes datos:



NUMERO
SERIE
Estado




10
A
Insertado Correctamente


10
B
Error, porque ya existe el número 10 registrado



En resumen se desea registrar boletas con serie A de la 1 a la 100 y registrar boletas con serie B de la 1 a la 100.
Agradezco desde ya cualquier ayuda, comentario u orientación que puedan proporcionar a mi duda.

PK compuesta...

gracias, lo voy a investigar y aplicar.

Deberias de generar una llave primaria compuesta, ya que nos permite generar una llave que se pueden combinar varios campos para generar la llave.
En tu caso podrias realizar el siguiente codigo:
--Se elimina la llave primaria ya creada
ALTER TABLE BOLETA
DROP CONSTRAINT nombre_llave;

--Se agrega la llave primaria compuesta
ALTER TABLE BOLETA
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_BOLETA PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO, SERIE);


Gracias @J. Castro por la ayuda, es sencillo pero sin la orientación y conocimiento no podía resolverlo, ahora debo resolver problemas con Restricciones, pero ya comprobé que si funciona.
